# Redshift SQL - Partition with CASE expression

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am attempting to create a rank with a partition which partitions by "cust_id" and ordered by "id" however I need the "rank" to increase based on the "variable" column.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of how I would like the result set to appear - Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM(variable)` as the window function instead of `RANK` / `ROW_NUMBER`:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  cust_id int,
  id int,
  variable int
);


INSERT INTO t VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 0),
(1, 3, 1),
(1, 4, 1),
(1, 5, 0),
(1, 6, 0),
(1, 7, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 0),
(2, 3, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
     , SUM(variable) OVER (
         PARTITION BY cust_id 
         ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       )
FROM t
ORDER BY cust_id, id;
```

| cust_id | id | variable | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXBdCXkYZWcGFAwF5hLFRp/0)

Comment: Thank you @marth - When i try this i am getting the following error:   ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: @user3482471: My bad, I don't have access to a redshift cluster right now so I just tried it out on postgresql. I added the explicit frame clause (i.e `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`), could you try again?

Comment: Amazing!! That is showing the result i was expecting!! Thank you VERY much